# Map key "F1" to left click in mac

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Map key "F1" on the external keyboard  to left-click  in mac

What is the simplest way? Is there any built-in setting that could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hammerspoon is too difficult to use.

[image]

Simply use karabiner-elements.